# Insert multiple rows from source

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Running SQL Server 2008.

I am making a temp table on each time this query is executed, and trying to find a way how to add multiple lines if there is more then 1 line to enter. I have a receipt information from the customer.

```
create table #temp (col1 varchar(100),col2 varchar(100),col3 varchar(100))

insert into #temp (col1, col2, col3)values('Store ID', '01', '')
insert into #temp (col1, col2, col3)values('Product','Quantity','Amount')
insert into #temp (col1, col2, col3)values
(
  (select product from receipt where receiptnum = 1),
  (select quantity from receipt where receiptnum = 1),
  (select amount from receipt where receiptnum = 1),
)
select * from #temp
```

Giving me me output of (this is my whole data structure, but same concept just so I don't flood code):
[image]

My Question is how can I do it if the receipt has more then 1 product, without knowing ahead. All that is needed for this data to show is receipt number and store number, so I don't know ahead the amount of rows to enter.

From looking around, it seems like I will have to use Cursor, but my knowledge of cursor is none.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the third insert statement with the below statement will insert all records into the temp table that were returned in the select.

```
insert into #temp
select product, quality, amount from receipt where receiptnum = 1
```

Comment: I have multiple inserts to format it as you see in the picture, including set value for 'Store ID', 'Register #' and such and then the value behind them gets input from the select query. Using your insert gives me :

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

because the other inserts are only adding one line. Otherwise yes, that does work.

Comment: The statement I proposed was to replace only your third insert.

Comment: I did that but that screamed at me because of all the other inserts. Which I did not edit. Your query works in none of the other inserts have a select statement in them. If I am just inserting raw data manually into them along with yours, no errors come up.